# React js Mapping Menu & Submenus

Tags: foreach, reactjs

**Here is my code:**

```
 ......
  render() {
    var menuItems = [
        {name: 'Item 1', subMenus: [{name: 'Sub Menu 1-2'}, {name: 'Sub Menu 1-2'}, {name: 'Sub Menu 1-3'}]},
        {name: 'Item 2'},
        {name: 'Item 3'},
        {name: 'Item 4', subMenus: [{name: 'Sub Menu 4-2'}, {name: 'Sub Menu 4-2'}, {name: 'Sub Menu 4-3'}]},
        {name: 'Item 5'}
    ]

    var menu  = function () {
        return (
            menuItems.forEach(function (menuItem, i) {
                if (menuItem.subMenus != undefined) {
                    <ul key={i}>menuItem.name
                    menuItem.subMenus.forEach(function (subMenu, i) {
                            <li key={i}>subMenu.name</li>
                        }
                        </ul>
                } else {
                    // do nothing
                }
            })
        )
    }

   return({menu})
   ......
```

Obviously it is not working.

What would be the correct procedure to loop thru a nested menu?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems here:

1. You're using a `forEach()` call instead of a `map()` call. You're creating `ul` components but you're not doing anything with them, they're just being thrown away.
2. You're not returning any components from the `render` method, you're return an object that contains a function that will generate components.
3. You're not interpolating JS into the JSX correctly. You have to surround JS expressions with brackets.
4. After you fix #1, you'll be returning a list of components from `render` when you can only return a single component. I wrapped everything in a `div` to fix that issue.

This is what you need:

```
return (
    <div>
        {menuItems.map(function(menuItem, i) {
            if (menuItem.subMenus != undefined) {
                return (
                    <ul key={i}>
                        {/* Not sure this is what you meant, but I added it anyway */}
                        {menuItem.name}
                        {menuItem.subMenus.map(function(subMenu, i) {
                            return <li key={i}>{subMenu.name}</li>;
                        })}
                    </ul>
                );
            } else {
                return undefined;
            }
        })}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: This will do nothing but return an new array containing the unsorted list, but you are not returning it to anything,  you forgot to wrap it in curly braces

Comment: You're right. Looks like my ninja edit had a mistake. :p

Answer (score 1):

```
  return (
        <div>
            {/* GJK forgot to encapsulate mapping in curly braces */} 
            {menuItems.map(function(menuItem, i) {
                if (menuItem.subMenus != undefined) {
                    return (
                        <ul key={i}>{menuItem.name}

                            {menuItem.subMenus.map(function(subMenu, i) {
                                return <li key={i}>{subMenu.name}</li>;
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    )
                } else {
                    return (
                        <ul key={i}>{menuItem.name}</ul>
                    )
                }
            })};
</div>)
```

Comment: upvoted this answer, though for readability i would, only place 
{ } <-- within the wrapper div within my return  for example if your component needs to return different (whatever), it could become a mess, so what i would normally do i is
render () {
  let whatever1 = this.whatever1();  <-- this function just returns the menuItem.map etc )

  let whatever2 = this.whatever2(); 
  return (
   <div>
    {whatever1}
    {whatever2}
</div>
  )
}